# Segmentation fault when adding object to vector

Tags: c++, qt, object, vector

When I add objects to vector "clientVect", I get a segmentation fault. Can you help me identify the problem?

This is the class:

```
#include "ClientDB.h"

ClientDB::ClientDB(){
}

ClientDB::~ClientDB(){
}


void ClientDB::addClient(QString name,QString fname,int id,QString bdate,int cellnb)
{
   Client c= Client(name,fname,id,bdate,cellnb);
   this->clientVect.push_back(c);
}

vector <vector<QString*> > ClientDB::showRenters(){
    using namespace std;
    int i;
    int j=0;
    QString id,cellnb,rentedcar;
    vector <vector<QString*> > list;
    for(i=0;i<clientVect.size();i++){
        if (clientVect[i].renter==true){
            (list[j]).push_back(&clientVect[i].name);
            (list[j]).push_back(&clientVect[i].fname);
            id=QString::number(clientVect[i].id);
            (list[j]).push_back(&id);
            (list[j]).push_back(&clientVect[i].bdate);
            cellnb=QString::number(clientVect[i].cellnb);
            (list[j]).push_back(&cellnb);
            rentedcar=QString::number(clientVect[i].rentedCar);
            (list[j]).push_back(&rentedcar);
            j++;
        }

    }
    return list;
}

vector <vector<QString*> > ClientDB::showAll(){
    using namespace std;
    int i;
    QString id,cellnb,rentedcar;
    vector <vector<QString*> > list;
    for(i=0;i<clientVect.size();i++){

            (list[i]).push_back(&clientVect[i].name);
            (list[i]).push_back(&clientVect[i].fname);
            id=QString::number(clientVect[i].id);
            (list[i]).push_back(&id);
            (list[i]).push_back(&clientVect[i].bdate);
            cellnb=QString::number(clientVect[i].cellnb);
            (list[i]).push_back(&cellnb);
            rentedcar=QString::number(clientVect[i].rentedCar);
            (list[i]).push_back(&rentedcar);
    }
    return list;
}
```

This is the header :

```
#ifndef CLIENTDB_H
#define CLIENTDB_H
#include "Client.h"
#include <vector>
#include <QString>

using namespace std;
class ClientDB
{
public:
    vector<Client>  clientVect;
    void addClient(QString,QString,int,QString,int);
    vector <vector<QString*> >showRenters();
    vector <vector<QString*> >showAll();
    ClientDB();
    ~ClientDB();
};

#endif // CLIENTDB_H
```

The problem is certainly in `ClientDB::addClient`, specifically in the `clientVect.push_back(....)`, but I can't see the reason.

Comment: Try attaching a debugger... you'll learn a ton! :)

Answer (score 1):

`showRenters()` and `showAll()` are both accessing `list` elements that have not been pushed yet and thus are invalid.  Even if the elements were valid, `showRenters()` and `showAll()` are also pushing multiple pointers to a same local variables, which is not going to work.  On each loop iteration, the variables get overwritten with new data, so you end up with multiple `vector` elements referring to the same physical data.  And worse, when `showRenters()` and `showAll()` exit, the variables go out of scope and get freed, leaving the returned vectors full of invalid pointers.

If you want to return a 2-dimensional vector of strings, use this instead:

```
vector <vector<QString> > ClientDB::showRenters(){
    using namespace std;
    vector <vector<QString> > list;
    // optional: list.reserve(clientVect.size());
    for(int i=0;i<clientVect.size();i++){
        if (clientVect[i].renter){
            vector<QString> values;
            // optional: values.reserve(6);
            values.push_back(clientVect[i].name);
            values.push_back(clientVect[i].fname);
            values.push_back(QString::number(clientVect[i].id));
            values.push_back(clientVect[i].bdate);
            values.push_back(QString::number(clientVect[i].cellnb));
            values.push_back(QString::number(clientVect[i].rentedCar));
            list.push_back(values);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

vector <vector<QString> > ClientDB::showAll(){
    using namespace std;
    vector <vector<QString> > list;
    // optional: list.reserve(clientVect.size());
    for(int i=0;i<clientVect.size();i++){
            vector<QString> values;
            // optional: values.reserve(6);
            values.push_back(clientVect[i].name);
            values.push_back(clientVect[i].fname);
            values.push_back(QString::number(clientVect[i].id));
            values.push_back(clientVect[i].bdate);
            values.push_back(QString::number(clientVect[i].cellnb));
            values.push_back(QString::number(clientVect[i].rentedCar));
            list.push_back(values);
    }
    return list;
}
```

```
vector <vector<QString> > list = db.showRenters(); // or showAll()
for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
    vector<QString> &values = list[i];
    // use values as needed...
}
```

Otherwise, change your code to return a 1-dimensional vector of `Client*` pointers instead, and let the caller decide what to do with the client data as needed.  As long as `clientVect` is not altered while the caller is using the returned vectors, the `Client*` pointers will remain valid:

```
vector <Client*> ClientDB::showRenters(){
    using namespace std;
    vector <Client*> list;
    // optional: list.reserve(clientVect.size());
    for(int i=0;i<clientVect.size();i++){
        if (clientVect[i].renter){
            list.push_back(&clientVect[i]);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

vector <Client*> ClientDB::showAll(){
    using namespace std;
    vector <Client*> list;
    // optional: list.reserve(clientVect.size());
    for(int i=0;i<clientVect.size();i++){
        list.push_back(&clientVect[i]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

```
vector <Client*> list = db.showRenters(); // or showAll()
for (int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
    Client *client = list[i];
    // use client as needed...
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i wasn't thinking straight :p .Could that be the reason to the segmentation fault ? because it only happens when i call  ClientDB::addClient.

Comment: The problem is not with `addClient()`.  The problem is with `showRenters()` and `showAll()` returning improperly filled vectors, causing the caller to access invalid data.